# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type classname as array

Tags: php

i have an array:

```
 Array
(
[0] => BugHerd_Project Object
    (
        [id:BugHerd_Project:private] => 24323
        [name:BugHerd_Project:private] => bugherd a
        [devurl:BugHerd_Project:private] => http://st.com/a/
        [active:BugHerd_Project:private] => 1
        [created:BugHerd_Project:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-05-03 11:15:22
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

        [updated:BugHerd_Project:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-05-05 06:55:52
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

    )

)
```

1. my code of accessing this array is:

- in this code im just fetching data from api .its simple http authentication code
- im using php wrapper here is the link :https://github.com/spekkionu/bugherd.
- from the api documentation they mention :curl -u api_key:x https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2/projects/1.json

  ```
   $api = new BugHerd_Api($email,$password);
  $projects = $api->listProjects();
  $i=0;
  on  doing print_r($projects[$i]['id:BugHerd_Project:private']);
  ```

  its result me error  so how should i access this array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access id property of a class, the property is private so yo cannot access directly to it (`$projects[$i]->id` don't work)

According to the BugHerd_Project class there's a getter to access this property `getId()`, try `$projects[$i]->getId()`

Comment: sr  i found in bug Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object give me some hint to resolve that issue.

Comment: Then you're trying to call the getId function on a non-object, post another question on SO, and post the code with the error

Comment: here is another error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string i used to call :print_r($projects_particular->getCreated()); api function :public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
  }

Comment: here is the output i recived :DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-05-05 10:04:30
    [timezone_type] => 2
    [timezone] => Z
)

Comment: i have the same problem too how to get the  date from datetime object